# Rotate ImageView without losing Height

Tags: android, imageview

I have a problem with an `ImageView` on Android Studio.

Basically, when i rotate the View (90°), the dimensions are swapped (Height is now Width and Width is now Height) causing the `ImageView` to go out of bounds.
It's been a struggle for 2 days now and i really need an answer.

[image: Normal:]

[image: Rotated:]

N.B - I use `setImageResource` for setting the resource in the `ImageView` programmatically

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out [this](https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout) library link as follows

Include this library dependency in your project's build.gradle

```
compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:3.0.0'
```

and for rotation purpose you need to wrap your view with "RotateLayout"

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:angle="90"> <!-- Specify rotate angle here -->

    <YourLayoutHere
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </YourLayoutHere>
</com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>
```

If you want rotate it programmtically then

```
int newAngle = rotateLayout.getAngle() + 90;
rotateLayout.setAngle(newAngle);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provide (you should provide examples of the layout, in this case), I think that what you need is to change `scaleType` in your image view.

See this article for a nice visual guide of the different options: [Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide).